# How to filter a column of data in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have loaded an xlsx file into Matlab using the

```
    data = xlsread()
```

Now there is a column which I would like to filter as per positive and negative values in the cells.

How would I go about this?

I am just starting, if someone can point out a good resource to learn how to program/code in matlab, I would be very grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
col = data(:,3);
gtz = col(col>0);
ltz = col(col<0);
eqz = col(col==0);
```

gives you the greater then zero, lower then zero and equal to zero values in column 3.

And searchich for 'Matlab tutorial' in your favorite search engine will bring you heaps of them.

Comment: Hi Tried it        col = AggregateNetRateofChange(:,3);
gtz = col(col>0);
ltz = col(col<0);
eqz = col(col==0);
Attempted to access AggregateNetRateofChange(:,3); index out of bounds because
size(AggregateNetRateofChange)=[11906,1].

Comment: Changed col = AggregateNetRateofChange(:,3) to (:,1). Seems to have worked going to see the files to confirm. Thanks a lot. Have a bunch of more questions. Using the helpfiles and Matlab Tutorial. :)